# How to lemmatize a certain word with spaCy

Tags: python, spacy

When I tried to lemmatize a sentence "I need you.", it seems like not right which is "need".

Here is the code.

```
aaa = nlp("I need you.")

for a in aaa:
    print(a.lemma_)
```

Here is the output.

```
-PRON-
ne
-PRON-
.
```

How can I get the right result about "need"?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you are getting 'ne' and not 'need'. I seem to get 'need':

```
doc = nlp("I need you.")
token = doc[1]
assert token.text == 'need'
```

Also, what's your Spacy version? Check that you have the latest version.

Comment: have you noticed you're using `text` instead `lemma_`?